# Trouble with temperature converter using readline function in C

Tags: c, readline, temperature

So I'm trying to do a temperature converter from Celsius to Fahrenheit, and for some reason the output for my code is all whacked out. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
  char *temperature = readline("Enter a temperature in celsius: ");

  double t1 = ((double)*temperature);
  double t2 = ((double)*temperature * 1.8) + 32;
  printf("%f° in Celsius is equivalent to %f° Fahrenheit.", t1, t2);
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Enter a temperature in celsius: 100
49.000000° in Celsius is equivalent to 120.200000° Fahrenheit.
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You're trying to turn a string into a double by typecasting.  That won't work.  Consider using `sscanf` something like `strtod` to convert a string to a double.

Answer (score 1):

After the call to `readline`, `temperature` contains a pointer to a buffer containing the string the user entered.  Then when you do this:

```
(double)*temperature
```

You're taking the character code of the first character in the string and converting it to type `double`.  So for example if the input was "100".  Then the first character is the character `'1'` whose ASCII code is 49.  That's why you get the value you're seeing.

You need to use the `strtod` function which converts a string representation of a number into a `double`:

```
double t1 = strtod(temperature, NULL);
double t2 = (t1 * 1.8) + 32;
```